# i want to store the response cookie in ajax and jquery request , is it possibly?

Tags: jquery, node.js, ajax

I want to store the response cookie in ajax and jquery request, is it possible?
 I can use node.js, but it's better that i can write it without server side languages.  Is it possible?

I tried:

```
$.ajax({
        url: "https://www.instagram.com/accounts/login/ajax",
        data: {
            queryParams: {"source": "desktop_nav"},
            username: 'arman_zareie',
            password: makeid()
        },
        method: 'POST',
        success: () => {}
    });
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can certainly write to and read from a cookie using `document.cookie`.  I personally like to use a utility to read and write from a cookie, like [jsCookie](https://github.com/js-cookie/js-cookie).

The real question is what do you want to store, and how sensitive is it?  Cookies created from client-side Javascript can be viewed by any user, whereas cookies created from the server can be kept only on the server and never sent to the client, which is more secure.

If you want to store response data, consider using the [WebStorage APIs](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Web_Storage_API).